# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "no te vayas" y "no te vayas a ir"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Si hay alguna diferencia en sentido o situaciones cuando se aplica.

He recibido "no te vayas a ir" de mi amiga (de Colombia) pero no estoy seguro como hay que interpretar esta frase.

Comment: ¿Este es el mensaje tal cual?  ¿o puso algo después como «No te vayas a ir a [un sitio]»?

Comment: La expresión "no [te] vayas a ..." puede ir seguida de cualquier verbo. En este caso el verbo que sigue es el mismo que usa la expresión ("ir"), lo cual es una casualidad desafortunada, puede confundir. Para entender la expresión, conviene partir de otros ejemplos ("no te vayas a enojar", "no vayas a olvidar las instrucciones", etc)

Answer (score 4):

"No te vayas" simply means "Don't leave". It is a mere request for the other party in a conversation not to leave.

---

The analysis of "No te vayas a ir" is a little bit more complicated. In Spanish, "**ir a** *<infinitive verb phrase>*" denotes that an action will be performed (or is intended to be performed) in some "near future". In English, this is roughly analogous to the use of the present continuous. For example:

> **Spanish:** Esta noche **vamos a** *cenar afuera*.
>
> **English:** Tonight we **are** *eating outside*.

And also:

> **Spanish:** ¿**No vas a** *salir a caminar*?
>
> **English:** **Aren't** you *going for a walk*?

```
Timeline

                present         near future (tonight)
-------------------|----------------------|-----------------------
               intend to             eat outside
                                    walk outside
```

The notion of "near future" is not necessarily relative to the present. Rather, it is relative to the tense in which the verb "ir" is conjugated. In particular, if "ir" is used in the past tense, the action was intended to be performed not too long after some fixed moment in the past. For example:

> **Spanish:** Ella **iba a** *regresar a su casa*.
>
> **English:** She **was about to** *go back home*.

```
Timeline

    fixed moment      immediately
    in the past       afterwards                 present
---------|-----------------|------------------------|-------------
     intend to        go back home
```

Spanish grammar has the awkward (and completely illogical) property that accusative and dative pronouns modifying an infinitive can be (and often are) "upgraded" to modify the "parent" modal verb instead. For example:

> **English:** I want to hug her.
>
> **Spanish:** Quiero abrazar*la*. [Literal translation.]
>
> **Spanish:** *La* quiero abrazar. [Illogical, but idiomatic.]

The "ir a <X>" construction defined above is no exception:

> **English:** I'm leaving.
>
> **Spanish:** Voy a irme.
>
> **Spanish:** Me voy a ir.

And now we can finally analyze our original phrase:

> **English:** Don't you (dare / intend to) leave!
>
> **Spanish:** ¡No vayas a irte!
>
> **Spanish:** ¡No te vayas a ir!

Answer (score 3):

(Ésta es una pregunta vieja pero nadie la ha respondido con claridad y es interesante, así que ahí voy.)

Para empezar: el *vayas* de *no te vayas* no es el mismo que el de *no te vayas a ir*. El *vayas* de *no te vayas* se corresponde con el *ir* de *no te vayas a ir*. En efecto, la misma construcción se puede emplear con cualquier otro verbo:

- *No te vayas a caer.*
- *No le vayas a decir nada.*
- *No se vaya usted a confundir.*
- *No vaya el señor a creer que yo soy así todo el tiempo.*

La construcción es un imperativo negativo, que toma la forma de adverbio de negación + subjuntivo de *ir*, seguido por *a* + verbo en infinitivo.

El verbo puede denotar acción voluntaria o involuntaria. En un imperativo simple también puede darse esto, por supuesto (*no te caigas*). Sin embargo en esta construcción parece que hay un elemento de voluntad o de atención extra que se le exige al sujeto, y quizá también un anticipo de falta de confianza en que se cumpla la orden, que no siempre aparece claramente en un imperativo simple.

- *No te vayas a caer* no sólo advierte sino que indica la necesidad de poner atención, incluso aunque no esté precedido de algo como *Ten cuidado* o *Mira bien dónde pisas*.
- *No se vaya usted a confundir* es a la vez menos fuerte y más exigente que *No se confunda usted*: no es una amenaza sino un pedido al otro de pensar muy bien antes de formarse una opinión.
- *No le vayas a decir nada* implica desconfianza en la capacidad del otro para guardar un secreto y refuerza la necesidad de guardarlo, cosa que no aparece en la orden simple *No le digas nada*.

Hay una inseguridad y una necesidad de refuerzo del imperativo en esta forma *no-vaya-X-a-hacer-Y* que no se encuentra en el imperativo negativo simple.

No sé si esto es así, pero a mí me parece que hay una relación entre esta forma y la del **futuro de conjetura**, que es el que usa el futuro simple del indicativo como expresión de hipótesis. Obsérvese que en vez del imperativo se podría usar una forma así:

- *No le irás a decir nada, ¿verdad?*
- *No irá el señor a creer eso de mí, ¿no?*

que según el tono y el contexto puede ser más tentativa y suave, o más perentoria o condescendiente.

Answer (score 2):

Si fuera a traducir "don't even think about leaving" en español, diría "no te vayas a ir".

Answer (score 0):

Son básicamente iguales, sin embargo, "No te vayas a ir" denota a su vez una ubicación que no se menciona pero que debe sobreentenderse y parece expresar mayor urgencia o una orden.

```
  "No te vayas a ir" (de ahí/de aquí)
```

ejemplo:

```
 "Ya casi llego, no te vayas a ir"="ya casi llego, no te vayas a ir de ahí"
 "Aún no has terminado, no te vayas a ir"="Aún no has terminado, no te vayas a ir de aquí"
```